# INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY with CTE

Tags: hadoop, hive

**Problem: Can't make file in directory when using cte**

I'm trying to use a CTE to get values to insert a file into a user directory. I've been able to successfully create the file in the directory without using a cte. Have tried putting the INSERT OVERWRITE block at beginning and before the SELECT portion of the WITH clause.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp.employee (
 id int,
 name string,
 age int,
 gender string )
 COMMENT 'Employee Table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp.salary (
 id int,
 salary int)
 COMMENT 'Employee Salary Table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

INSERT INTO emp.employee values(1,'scott',23,'M');
INSERT INTO emp.employee values(2,'raman',50,'M');
INSERT INTO emp.salary values(1,30000);
INSERT INTO emp.salary values(2,40000);
```

**Query to create file**

```
WITH cte_age AS
(
SELECT 
    lowest_age = MIN(age)
,   id

FROM emp.employee 

GROUP BY
    id
)

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/doe/lowest_age'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

SELECT
    la.id
,   la.lowest_age
,   s.salary

FROM cte_lowest_age as la

INNER JOIN emp.salary AS s ON
    la.id = s.id;
```

**Error**

I've tried putting the INSERT OVERWRITE block at the beginning as well with same error

`Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 20:18 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in statement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolon after STORED AS TEXTFILE was terminating the CTE early. Correct answer:

```
ITH cte_age AS
(
SELECT 
    lowest_age = MIN(age)
,   id

FROM emp.employee 

GROUP BY
    id
)

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/doe/lowest_age'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE

SELECT
    la.id
,   la.lowest_age
,   s.salary

FROM cte_lowest_age as la

INNER JOIN emp.salary AS s ON
    la.id = s.id;
```